# Permissions problem installing python 2.5.4 from source

Tags: python, install-from-source

I was trying to install Python 2.5.4 to my ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I downloaded the package from their website [Python 2.5.4 Release](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4) and I did everything they told me to, but when trying to "execute" the command:

```
make install
```

I get the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/install -c python /usr/local/bin/python2.5
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/python2.5': Permiss
ion denied
make: *** [altbininstall] Error 1
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You do realize that Python is installed per default? Any reason you need Python 2.5.4?

Comment: I need this version specifically for educational purposes, [link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/software/)..

Comment: problem solved using  **sudo make install**

Comment: To people considering close-voting: This has an answer and will be potentially useful others. Rather than casting a close vote, I recommend upvoting [the answer that solved the problem](http://askubuntu.com/a/194889/22949).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make

```
sudo make install
```

Without using sudo, you do not gain the root privileges necessary to install files in system directories.

Comment: @Muhammad What other problem you are facing now

Comment: @Anwar could find the IDLE for python 2.5.4, I am using it by typing `python2.5` in the Terminal, any solution for that??

Comment: @Muhammad I suggest you to ask another question regarding this new problem and also mention about this question there.